# layouts - make a sibling my child

Tags: layout, blocks, layout-update, methods

lets say there's the following hierarchy of blocks:

```
<block name="parent">
    <block name="child" />
</block>
```

and I want to push a block of my own inside "parent", and put the original "child" as a child of my new block, eg:

```
<block name="parent">
    <block name="my_block">
        <block name="child" />
    </block>
</block>
```

how can I do it via layout xml?

I tried something like:

```
<reference name="parent">
     <block name="my_block">
           <action method="setChild"><name>child</name><block>child</block></action>
     </block>            
</reference>
```

but it didn't work (I tried calling getChildHtml('child'); ?> inside my template, and got an error.

am I doing it right? how do I update an existing block, add a block of my own, and turn one of the siblings (that were originally in parent) to be a child of my new block?

thanks!

Comment: I believe your example above is actually the valid method for this. Try that and call it via `getChildHtml()` method, it should work.

Comment: I did, its not working. I don't get any errors or log reports, but the template just stop rendering at that line (if for example I have "foo", then getChildHtml(), and then "goo", I will only see "foo" rendered).
how can I debug this?? I'm pretty sure its because the child is not really there... thanks

Comment: If it's working without your custom block, then it should with your custom block too. Just to make things clear, your method 1 (Without action node) is what I meant with the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `insert` or `append` instead of `setChild`, otherwise the block is not added to the `sortedChildren` array.

Also, you create a new block, "my_block", that replaces the old "my_block", instead of referencing the existing block.

## Solution

```
 <reference name="my_block">
       <action method="append"><block>child</block></action>
 </reference>
```